# Can't filter Calendar according to event date instead of date added

Tags: datetime

Hi I'm trying to figure out this issue as well. i have calendar that only shows the dates the event has been posted, not the actual start date for which I created the field. 
I can't seem to filter dates according to their start day. When I try to filter it, it's not giving me the date field option. :( Can someone direct me toward good tutorial or help me set it up. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up the Date argument. See Drupal therapy's video tutorial on this http://www.drupaltherapy.com/date. Also here's an output a properly configure calendar view

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'calendar';
$view->description = 'A multi-dimensional calendar view with back/next navigation.';
$view->tag = 'Calendar';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'field' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
  ),
  'field_date_value' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'time_only',
    'multiple' => array(
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_to' => '',
      'group' => 0,
    ),
    'repeat' => array(
      'show_repeat_rule' => 'hide',
    ),
    'fromto' => array(
      'fromto' => 'value',
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_date_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_date',
    'field' => 'field_date_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'sticky' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'id' => 'sticky',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'sticky',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_date_value' => array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'delta' => '-1',
    'id' => 'field_date_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_date',
    'field' => 'field_date_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'date_argument' => array(
    'default_action' => 'default',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'date',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'date_fields' => array(
      'node_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'node_data_field_date.field_date_value',
    ),
    'year_range' => '-1:+1',
    'date_method' => 'OR',
    'granularity' => 'month',
    'id' => 'date_argument',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'date_argument',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'product' => 0,
      'event' => 0,
      'audio' => 0,
      'blog' => 0,
      'gallery' => 0,
      'gallery_image' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
      'simplenews' => 0,
      'story' => 0,
      'video' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 1,
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'event_product' => 'event_product',
      'event' => 'event',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'role' => array(),
  'perm' => '',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('title', 'Calendar');
$handler->override_option('header_empty', 1);
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 0);
$handler->override_option('use_more', 0);
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'calendar_nav');
$handler = $view->new_display('calendar', 'Calendar page', 'calendar_1');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'field' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
  ),
  'field_date_value' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 1,
      'text' => '([field_date_value])',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'time_only',
    'multiple' => array(
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_to' => '',
      'group' => 0,
    ),
    'repeat' => array(
      'show_repeat_rule' => 'hide',
    ),
    'fromto' => array(
      'fromto' => 'both',
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_date_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_date',
    'field' => 'field_date_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('path', 'calendar');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('calendar_colors', array(
  '0' => array(),
));
$handler->override_option('calendar_colors_vocabulary', array());
$handler->override_option('calendar_colors_taxonomy', array());
$handler->override_option('calendar_colors_group', array());
$handler->override_option('calendar_popup', 0);
$handler->override_option('calendar_date_link', '');
$handler = $view->new_display('calendar_block', 'Calendar block', 'calendar_block_1');
$handler->override_option('block_description', 'Calendar');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
$handler = $view->new_display('calendar_period', 'Year view', 'calendar_period_1');
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'calendar_style');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'display_type' => 'year',
  'name_size' => 1,
  'max_items' => 0,
));
$handler->override_option('attachment_position', 'after');
$handler->override_option('inherit_arguments', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_exposed_filters', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_pager', FALSE);
$handler->override_option('render_pager', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('displays', array(
  'calendar_1' => 'calendar_1',
  'default' => 0,
  'calendar_block_1' => 0,
));
$handler->override_option('calendar_type', 'year');
$handler = $view->new_display('calendar_period', 'Month view', 'calendar_period_2');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'field' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
  ),
  'field_date_value' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 1,
      'text' => '([field_date_value])',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'time_only',
    'multiple' => array(
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_to' => '',
      'group' => 0,
    ),
    'repeat' => array(
      'show_repeat_rule' => 'hide',
    ),
    'fromto' => array(
      'fromto' => 'both',
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_date_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_date',
    'field' => 'field_date_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'calendar_style');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'name_size' => '2',
  'with_weekno' => '0',
  'max_items' => '0',
  'max_items_behavior' => 'more',
  'groupby_times' => 'hour',
  'groupby_times_custom' => '',
  'groupby_field' => '',
));
$handler->override_option('attachment_position', 'after');
$handler->override_option('inherit_arguments', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_exposed_filters', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_pager', FALSE);
$handler->override_option('render_pager', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('displays', array(
  'calendar_1' => 'calendar_1',
  'default' => 0,
  'calendar_block_1' => 0,
));
$handler->override_option('calendar_type', 'month');
$handler = $view->new_display('calendar_period', 'Day view', 'calendar_period_3');
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'calendar_style');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'name_size' => '99',
  'with_weekno' => 0,
  'max_items' => 0,
  'max_items_behavior' => 'more',
  'groupby_times' => 'hour',
  'groupby_times_custom' => '',
  'groupby_field' => '',
));
$handler->override_option('attachment_position', 'after');
$handler->override_option('inherit_arguments', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_exposed_filters', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_pager', FALSE);
$handler->override_option('render_pager', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('displays', array(
  'calendar_1' => 'calendar_1',
  'default' => 0,
  'calendar_block_1' => 0,
));
$handler->override_option('calendar_type', 'day');
$handler = $view->new_display('calendar_period', 'Week view', 'calendar_period_4');
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'calendar_style');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'name_size' => '99',
  'with_weekno' => 0,
  'max_items' => 0,
  'max_items_behavior' => 'more',
  'groupby_times' => 'hour',
  'groupby_times_custom' => '',
  'groupby_field' => '',
));
$handler->override_option('attachment_position', 'after');
$handler->override_option('inherit_arguments', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_exposed_filters', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_pager', FALSE);
$handler->override_option('render_pager', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('displays', array(
  'calendar_1' => 'calendar_1',
  'default' => 0,
  'calendar_block_1' => 0,
));
$handler->override_option('calendar_type', 'week');
$handler = $view->new_display('calendar_period', 'Block view', 'calendar_period_5');
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'calendar_style');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'display_type' => 'month',
  'name_size' => '1',
));
$handler->override_option('attachment_position', 'after');
$handler->override_option('inherit_arguments', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_exposed_filters', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('inherit_pager', FALSE);
$handler->override_option('render_pager', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('displays', array(
  'calendar_1' => 0,
  'default' => 0,
  'calendar_block_1' => 'calendar_block_1',
));
$handler->override_option('calendar_type', 'month');
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Upcoming', 'block_1');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'field' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
  ),
  'field_date_value_1' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'time_only',
    'multiple' => array(
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_to' => '',
      'group' => 0,
    ),
    'repeat' => array(
      'show_repeat_rule' => 'hide',
    ),
    'fromto' => array(
      'fromto' => 'both',
    ),
    'exclude' => 1,
    'id' => 'field_date_value_1',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_date',
    'field' => 'field_date_value',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'field_date_value' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 1,
      'text' => '[field_date_value] <br />([field_date_value_1])',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'date_no_time',
    'multiple' => array(
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_to' => '',
      'group' => 0,
    ),
    'repeat' => array(
      'show_repeat_rule' => 'hide',
    ),
    'fromto' => array(
      'fromto' => 'both',
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_date_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_date',
    'field' => 'field_date_value',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
  ),
  'field_teaser_value' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 1,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'label_type' => 'none',
    'format' => 'default',
    'multiple' => array(
      'group' => TRUE,
      'multiple_number' => '',
      'multiple_from' => '',
      'multiple_reversed' => FALSE,
    ),
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'field_teaser_value',
    'table' => 'node_data_field_teaser',
    'field' => 'field_teaser_value',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array());
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 1,
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'date_filter' => array(
    'operator' => '>=',
    'value' => array(
      'min' => NULL,
      'max' => NULL,
      'value' => NULL,
      'default_date' => 'now',
      'default_to_date' => '',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'date_fields' => array(
      'node_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'node_data_field_date.field_date_value',
    ),
    'date_method' => 'OR',
    'granularity' => 'day',
    'form_type' => 'date_select',
    'default_date' => 'now',
    'default_to_date' => '',
    'year_range' => '-1:+1',
    'id' => 'date_filter',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'date_filter',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('title', 'Upcoming Events');
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 4);
$handler->override_option('use_more', 1);
$handler->override_option('use_more_always', 1);
$handler->override_option('use_more_text', 'view calendar');
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'default');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'grouping' => '',
));
$handler->override_option('block_description', 'Upcoming');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

Comment: The view is drupal-6 specific. Would love to have such a view for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

In D6 and Views 2 (not positive about D7), you need to change the Date argument in Views.  If using the default Calendar to start, click on `Date: Date (node)`, scroll down to **Date field(s)** and mark the checkbox of the field you wish to use.  Then to filter the events, add a new filter and find `Content: YOUR DATE FIELD` and set the filter settings.

Not knowing what version of Drupal you are using, here are some resources that might also be useful to you to get started:

[D7 Calendar installation & configuration](http://drupaltherapy.com/date_d7) (Screencast)
[D6 Calendar installation & configuration](http://vimeo.com/6544779) (Screencast)
[How to create an Upcoming Events list](http://vimeo.com/6547042)  (Screencast)
[Date/Calendar Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/262062)